# Stroking Merged shapes not working as expected

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a simple question. I was reading [this](http://www.photoshoptutorials.ws/photoshop-tutorials/special-effects/quick-tip-create-fun-spirographs-fractals/) tutorial. And I couldn't get the effect as expected. After some experiments I found that when I merge two shapes and apply stroke only its outline gets a stroke. For example I draw 2 rectangles and merged them. This is what I got: 
[image]

I would like to have stroke also inside the shape. How to do this?

**EDIT:**
This is what I got doing above tutorial

[image]

What is expected:

[image]

My path options:

[image]

Comment: errr.. don't merge the shapes.

Comment: @Scott Actually its not about merging. I want to do some "Transform again" to get a spirograph effect. So when I do it, its automatically gets merged.

Comment: It shouldn't get auot-merged if the shape layers are **separate layers** and the path option are set correctly.

Comment: @Scott Can you please take a look at this  http://www.photoshoptutorials.ws/photoshop-tutorials/special-effects/quick-tip-create-fun-spirographs-fractals I'll update what I got doing that.

Comment: Rahul, the starting shape layer needs to be a layer by itself, not merged. Then everything works as the tutorial explains.

Comment: @Scott I'm really sorry, I couldn't get it. I did this: Create a new layer > draw Ellipse> Ctr+T> 15º transform> Shift+Ctr+Alt+T several times. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before drawing your first shape, be certain the path options are set to "New Layer"

[image: new layer]

This will **not** cause the shapes to be merged, but rather each shape will be its own layer. You can then add layer styles as needed to each layer.

### UPDATE: Figured out your issue.

- Draw the first shape
- **SWITCH TO THE *MOVE TOOL***
- Now, proceed to do the transform to rotate then the step and repeating.

If you don't switch back to the **Move Tool** then the path stays active on the same live shape and the paths merge. When you transformed to rotate you were getting a pop up message about a Live Shape being converted to a regular path, weren't you? that would have been a helpful clue.

Comment: "New layer" is already selected :(

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you. There should be no "auto-merging" taking place. Each shape should be its own layer.

Comment: What about "Transform"? Isn't there a "step'n'repeat" style effect you can apply using offsets and *n* copies without cluttering up document with 120 (etc) layers?.

Comment: @horatio is step and repeat accessed by Alt+Ctr+T? It also merges shapes. I dont know whats wrong.

Comment: no. This is under "Effect>Distort&Transform>Transform" I think. Scott is more of an expert on AI than I am. I avoid it unless I have to.

Comment: I'm aware it's Photoshop @horatio :) I don't know why he's getting merged shapes if the path options are set correctly. All I can think is there's some setting somewhere being missed. By default, the tutorial works exactly as it's explained.

Comment: haha. sorry I thought AI this whole time :P

Comment: Well, I have even tried resetting all tools, and then all preferences. Nothing helps, I think I should try re installing Ps. :D

Comment: @rahul I updated this answer with a solution.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the update. But from the beginning I did selected move tool before transforming, I never knew why until you said it. But now I noticed that even if I selected Move tool the path is still active. So it merges shapes as you said. And I never got any warnings by the way. But fun part is, don't know why or how unchecking View-> Extras solves the issue. Now when I select move tool the shape no longer active and I could Transform again to new layers! It such a small thing, but feels good when found It. Thanks... :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using an earlier version than you or Scott (as far as I can tell), but I can reproduce the behavior.

In my case, a shape is represented on the palette as a color layer and a layer mask. When I hit ctrl+alt+shift+T (hereafter "the Key"), I get one new layer as expected HOWEVER all further repetitions of the Key are all pasted into the same single shape mask and the stroke is applied to the merged shapes.

The problem for me is that the after hitting the Key, the new layer's shape mask is highlighted which is why the new shape is pasted into the mask instead of creating a new layer. If I deselect the mask by clicking on it, then the Key creates a new layer.

The key combo for selecting the bottom layer is `alt+,` and the key for selecting the top layer is `alt+.`

Try `ctrl+alt+shift+T` `alt+,` `alt+.` repeat.